# Any Pdfinfo -terminal tool in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, pdf

I am trying to find any default tool in OS X by which you can see in Terminal the encodinf of a pdf file.

You can do this visually by clicking info on the file.

For instance, such files which have *Mac OS X 10.10.2 Quartz PDFContext* I want to get out of my System.
So my task is actually find those files and then find original ones and convert them correctly to right encoding via LaTeX.

### Outputs of the commands in answers

Command `mdls` in fd0's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/227586/15504)

```
mdls -name kMDItemEncodingApplications -raw OxfordDictionary.pdf
```

gives

```
(
    "3-Heights(TM) PDF Producer 2.0.5.0 (http://www.pdf-tools.com); modified using iTextSharp 5.0.0 (c) 1T3XT BVBA"
```

Installation of `brew install Caskroom/cask/pdfinfo` wants sudo so I had to reject it in my current settings. The `mdls` seems to work sufficiently.

---

How can you see the encoding of pdf-file in OS X Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mdls` instead of installing external tools.

```
mdls -name kMDItemEncodingApplications -raw file.pdf
```

Comment: Great! Than you for pointing this out. The installation of pdinfo requires sude which does not make sense. I had to reject it in my current setting. I added an example output of your command in the body of the question. Your command seems to work sufficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Just get Xpdf 3.04 from [foolabs](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html).

If your current system is Yosemite get the precompiled binaries: [xpdfbin-mac-3.04](ftp://ftp.foolabs.com/pub/xpdf/xpdfbin-mac-3.04.tar.gz). The 64-bit installer available [there](http://kaiser-edv.de/downloads/XPDF%20Tools.dmg) doesn't work. Uncompress/Untar the tar.gz and install this binary package manually:

1. Copy the 64-bit executables (xpdf, pdftotext, etc.) to to /usr/local/bin.
2. Copy the man pages (*.1 and *.5) to /usr/local/man/man1 and
   /usr/local/man/man5.
3. Copy the sample-xpdfrc file to /usr/local/etc/xpdfrc.  You'll
   probably want to edit its contents (as distributed, everything is
   commented out) -- see xpdfrc(5) for details.

Check your $PATH if the executables don't work.

If your current system is Mavericks, Mountain Lion or Lion the above-mentioned 64-bit installer should work.

Now continue like Matteo mentioned:

To extract it with `pdfinfo`:

```
pdfinfo file.pdf | grep ^Producer
```

Comment: Or install it via brew these days: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277784/17800

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install it using mac ports, you should install the package xpdf OR xpdf-tools, for example:

```
sudo port install xpdf-tools
```

and then extract the information you need:

```
pdfinfo file.pdf | grep ^Producer
```

Comment: This info was very helpful. MacPorts has this tool in "xpdf-tools".

Answer (score 0):

The tool you mention `pdfinfo` is available on OS X, for example by installing [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) and then

```
sudo port install pdfinfo
```

About the second part of your question: `Mac OS X 10.10.2 Quartz PDFContext` is not an encoding but the *producer*.

To extract it with `pdfinfo`:

```
pdfinfo file.pdf | grep ^Producer
```

Comment: It would be great if this can be done without external tools. Just with standard tools.

Comment: But you mentioned `pdfinfo` yourself... Anyway I don't think that OS X has some similar by default (either by using `string` and `grep` ...)

Comment: Installed MacPorts -> Error: Port pdfinfo not found

Comment: You need `brew install Caskroom/cask/pdfinfo` in El Capitan.